# Which data dump has the information related to mentioned users in a comment

Tags: support, comments, data-explorer, data-dump

From the Stack Exchange API, I can retrieve the comments in which a specific user is mentioned using @ method.

[Here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/mentions-on-users) is the `/users/{ids}/mentioned` API.

Which data dump on archive.org hosts this information. I thought the `Comments.xml` dump might have this info. But I don't see a field called "in_reply_to" or something there.

Then I checked out [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/744448) answer which describes the schemas of all tables. However, none of these tables has an attribute like "mentioned" or "in_reply_to". Can someone please point me to the correct data dump?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That information is not available in the data-dump or in SEDE for that matter.

You could to some extent recreate that API feature with this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/1335459?UserId=31766)

```
select postid as [Post Link]
     , id as [Comment Link]
from comments
where text like concat(
    '%@'
  , (select displayname 
     from users 
     where id = ##userid?31766##)
  , ' %')
```

but that is a brittle workaround at best and will fail for users that have changed their displayname often and/or have similar usernames.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the very useful [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the awesome [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).